# React blank screen in Springboot using Thymeleaf

Tags: java, reactjs, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have a requirement where I want to use React code using Thymeleaf.
I used create-react-app and npm start works fine. Did not add any other code to it.
Here is my setup-
src\main\resources\templates\index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Getting Started: Serving Web Content</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <link href="/css/main.5f361e03.chunk.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="/js/2.b38996be.chunk.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/main.8a01ac9e.chunk.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="root"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

You can see that I have linked my React and CSS build code above.

src\main\resources\static
This location has the css, js, media folders

[image: Everything looks good here]

When I go to http://localhost:8080/ the front-end is empty.

This is my pom file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web-services</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Link to Github project-
https://github.com/kedarnadkarny/springreact

Answer (score 0):

I believe your issue because in index.html you forgot to load /static/main-runtime*.js
That runtime is required to load your reactjs app.

You can use this maven plugin https://github.com/maasdi/react-assets-maven-plugin to automated this process.

PS: I had similar problem, and I have to create plugin to solve this.